# Can't run Rails 4.1.7 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have done the following commands :

1. rails new [app_name] [Ex. Demo]
2. cd demo [I entered into the directory]
3. rails -s (0r) rails -server

When I run this command I receive the following errors.

```
/home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/uglifier-2.5.3/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/uglifier-2.5.3/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
from /home/burhani/demo/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/burhani/demo/bin/rails:8:in `require'
from /home/burhani/demo/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
from /home/burhani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/burhani/demo/bin/spring:16:in `require'
from /home/burhani/demo/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

What I want to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run rails s not (rails -s)

Comment: Sorry I entered rails s only.

Answer (score 0):

Your error `Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)` means you don't have Javascript runtime installed. Install Node.js (it's useful for mane other purposes, too). On Ubuntu:

```
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Also you have to install build tools:

```
$ apt-get install -y build-essential
```

Then you'll be able to run `rails server` command.